# Why does trying to add a row to a dataframe yield the error of the truth value of the dataframe being ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some testing code as shown below:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(columns=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
res.loc[len(res)] = pd.DataFrame([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

But it causes this error to be shown:

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

But `len(res)` is simply a number and not a boolean mask, so its not and `and &` and `or |` thing causing the error like what I saw on SO when I searched the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a **Series** (or list) as it's 1D, not a DataFrame that is 2D:

```
res.loc[len(res)] = pd.Series([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

# or
# res.loc[len(res)] = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  5  6  7  8  9
```

Comment: Found out that its also ok to leave it in list form without converting to df/series

Comment: Yes, a list would work, I should have mentioned it ;)